# how to restore if user privileges modified of a database?

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL Database with GUI workbench installed. I forgot one database user account password, so that I am unable to connect to it remotely.

How can I resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html)

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'bob'@'%.example.org' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

If you have not having domain , then you can add IP also.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'bob'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

if you need to reset the root password see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: what about privileges ? is there any wild character which can stand for granting all permissions ?

Comment: if you use user the same the priviliges will remain the same.